# Rename [google-apps-marketplace] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

**Update:**
while original request was not being processed on SO, Google renamed their marketplace again.

As noted in developer docs, now it is named *Google Workspace Marketplace*: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace

> The Google Workspace Marketplace makes it easy for enterprise users and Google Workspace domain administrators to find and install third-party applications that are integrated with Google Workspace.

---

Google Apps Marketplace is now *G Suite Marketplace*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_Suite_Marketplace

New questions for G Suite Marketplace is being posted with old tag slug [google-apps-marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-marketplace).

Comment: And...now it's Google Workspace Marketplace, which as google-workspace-marketplace would *just* fit

Comment: @JesseScherer you can get Workspace from Google Workspace Marketplace: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/workspace/852754008567

Comment: [gsuite-addons] should be desynominised from [google-apps-script], and then renamed to [google-workspace-addons] as per the [new alternate runtimes](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes-overview). [guite] should also become [google-workspace]. [gsuite-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite-services)? Burn it.

Comment: I just made a separate request for "gsuite" --> "google-workspace": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402071/rename-gsuite-to-google-workspace

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - since it was only 6 questions and all of them were either borderline off-topic (about general usage of GSuite) or about certain APIs missing from the tag list, I edited the questions, fixed some other issues, and purged the tag. Tomorrow there won't be a [tag:gsuite-services] tag anymore (if folks will manage not to slap it on a question for a day).

Comment: @JesseScherer  We would probably need a consolidation project just for renaming to "workspace" :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402074/