# Rename [gsuite] to [google-workspace]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

G Suite is now Google Workspace, as noted in [the developer docs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite):

> The Google Workspace developer platform is a collection of tools and resources that let you customize, extend, and integrate with Google Workspace. Low-code tools like Apps Script enable business users to build customizations that automate routine tasks, and professional resources like Add-ons and APIs enable software vendors to build applications that extend and integrate with Google Workspace.

#### Related:

- [Rename [google-apps-marketplace] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394343/rename-google-apps-marketplace-tag) - This deals with [google-apps-marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-marketplace) and not [gsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite) tag.
- [Remove synonym [gsuite-addons] from [google-apps-script] and rename [gsuite-addons] to [google-workspace-add-ons]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402074/remove-synonym-gsuite-addons-from-google-apps-script-and-rename-gsuite-addo)

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Probably should create a new tag and synonymize rather than rename, to reduce disruption and confusion among those uninformed of the name change.

Comment: @zcoop98 - that's a good idea (consider adding an answer with the proposal). After all, G Suite existed for a while, and will probably linger in user consciousness for a time. Jesee, how about making [tag:gsuite] a synonym of a tag [tag:google-workspace]? I am worried that users will recreate the GSuite tag when they find out it is missing. That said, usually renaming requests are treated just as proposed - the old name, if it was featured prominently, is made a synonym.

Comment: I think if someone recreates [gsuite], it can be synonymized. Currently, Google renamed every reference of gsuite in all their documentations into workspace. It's highly unlikely for a programmer to miss the name change, if they bothered to look at documentation even once.

Comment: @TheMaster - the last part of your comment is what bothers me most :) If you say so, but making a synonym upfront should not be a big deal - let's close the issue before it can happen (also I am worried that new users will simply stop slapping either if they don't see the old tag in their question box)

Comment: It already started - we already have 2 questions with [tag:google-workspace] and if we do not do anything, the fragmentation will grow exponentially (once users will get used to G Workspace name and will start to find the tag more and more). I am in the middle of updating the G Suite tag wiki page to include new info and usage guidance

Comment: I submitted an update to the wiki and excerpt - feel free to improve upon, expand or change: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gsuite/info

Comment: @OlegValter Maybe we should synonymize gsuite(child) to Google-workspace(parent) until  mods can get to this request.

Comment: @TheMaster - yeah, I thought so as well, just started with updating the wiki - after all, the wiki info can be transferred after that regardless of whether the request is noticed or not - win/win. I can get behind synonymizing - the only problem is tag score, we need to tag the [tag:google-workspace] to a couple of questions we answered with good score, then wait and synonymize.

Comment: @OlegValter Would be a bit hard to find 5 users. I renamed some of the questions where I have score(Will be able to  propose tomorrow). [Alternatively, We could do a full fledged rename of all 1k gsuite questions]

Comment: @TheMaster  Ok, I should have mine tomorrow as well, had a couple of well-received answers thankfully. Isn't bulk rename a bit too much? We can organize the synonym effort in chat - we have at least 4 people who are active in all things Google. Plus someone might see the voting.

Comment: @OlegValter I added a answer for a public opinion/objections, if any. We should be able to start the synonym process tomorrow.

Comment: An update: the wiki edit updating the info and introducing usage guidance is approved, so all we need is to make the synonym link, and we are all set

Answer (score 5):

#### Update Final:

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by [Machavity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity)

Tags merged.

---

#### Update1:

Based on Community consensus, [gsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite) synonymized to => [google-workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace).

Merge/Rename still pending.

---

Until moderators can actually get to this issue, Concerned users should be able to make a interim synonym between [gsuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite) => [google-workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-workspace) to avoid fragmentation.

Comment: While G Suite is not available for new subscriptions, the "change" from G Suite to Google Workpace is not automatic. See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402680/1595451) for details

Comment: Tags merged since they are synonymed (anyone looking for gsuite will still find it as the new tag)

Answer (score -3):

I think that the rename should not be done yet as G Suite is still "alive"

From [G Suite is now Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10075155)

> **Can I keep my current G Suite subscription?**
>
> We’ll be sharing additional information over the coming months about the transition from your current G Suite subscription to one of the new editions. If you have an active Annual/Fixed-Term contract your subscription will remain unchanged.
>
> You can transition to one of the new Google Workspace editions in the next few months, or when your current commit period ends.

From [G Suite Basic edition](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6047848?hl=en)

> G Suite Basic is not available for new sign ups. If you have G Suite Basic, your subscription and all related services will continue to function as they do today, until it’s time to transition to a new offering. We’ll be in touch over the coming months to identify your transition path.

Comment: Given that [all gsuite editions basically come under "Google workspace"](https://support.google.com/a/topic/4425947), I think it's not  right to wait until legacy editions which are not offered by Google("Legacy free edition" stopped in 2012) are specifically renamed or stopped. They account for a very small minority and practically the issues faced by such minority would still be the same, even after a rename.

Comment: Rubén, I think it is practical to do the transition now as everything is renamed and all G Suite links I am aware of redirect to Google Workspace despite the transitional period. After all, we will not be merging the tags, but creating a synonym link, which will serve well both users on the current subscription and transitioned ones by reducing the fragmentation. By the time the period ends, I am afraid we will have a worse time merging already diverged paths down the line

Comment: Besides, I am not sure if subscription concerns are relevant to on-topic questions we answer here - G Suite Add-ons are already renamed to Workspace Add-ons, so are the Google APIs to [Google Workspace APIs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/aspects/apis). I think if we do not act now (or in the nearest future), we will end up with a bunch of naturally created `*-workspace` tags that will increase the already not-so-good entropy of `google-*` tag mapping :(

Comment: Google periodically renames them anyways. I started using it when it was "Google Apps" (not to be confused with Google Play Store, where you buy and download Android Apps). The rename is basically a done deal.

Comment: @Machavity I also started used it then :) Anyway, let see what questions arises, if any, during the transition from G Suite to Google Workspace.

Comment: @OlegValter The change from G Suite to Google Workspace is not just a name/logo update. Anyway this request is alredy [meta-tag:status-completed]. Let see what happens.

Comment: @Rubén - I understand that it is not, but what does it matter in terms of a pragmatic approach to tagging questions? I am not sure if there is a real (not as a theoretical possibility) issue that would be addressed by postponing the rename. In other words, what is the *significant* difference between GSuite and GWorkspace going forward?

Comment: @OlegValter What is more pragmatic that keeping things as they are when they aren't broken and the change doesn't offer a significative improvent?

Comment: AFAIK the transition guides from G Suite to Google Workspace will be communicated directly by Google to each G Suite admin.

Comment: @Rubén I literally don't get what we, as developers, benefit from keeping the G Suite naming? That's my only concern here - I understand that there are issues business-wise,  but in terms of services and APIs, which we should primarily be concerned with - is there are reason to postpone? We already have tags [tag:google-workspace] creeping up - let's deal with it while it is easy.

Comment: Our concern is fragmentation. [Someone already created [google-workspace\] and it already had 2 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402071/rename-gsuite-to-google-workspace#comment806650_402071)

Comment: @TheMaster At this time I'm not concerned about that.